# Error in pattern in Watson Assistant Entity

Tags: regex, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to make a regex pattern for a Watson Assistant Entity that detects dates similar to those in bold:

- date 25/2/2020 30/2/2020
- date /25/2 **30/2** of
- date **18/02** of
- date 12/12/ of
- date 12/12/
- date **12/12**

I have used the following expression to do it:

```
( \b(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([\-/.])(1[1-2]|0?[1-9])(?![\-/.])\b )
```

This expression works well, the problem is that the pattern comparison engine that is used in Watson, has syntax limitations.

Entity patterns cannot contain:

- Positive repetitions (for example, x*+)
- Previous references (for example, \g1)
- Conditional branches (for example, (? (Cond) true))

At this point, I cannot use (?![-/.]) to avoid dates like '25/02/2020'.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What regex engine is your pattern based on? Have you tried converting it to Java regex? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: The regular expression engine is loosely based on the Java regular expression engine. (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant-icp?topic=assistant-private-entities)

Comment: What is the actual rule (in human words) for a date to match? I find it difficult to understand what you need / intend.

Comment: It has to match only when the format is day/month. If it is day/month/year it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this:

```
[ ]((?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([\-/.])(1[1-2]|0?[1-9]))(?:$|[^\d\-/.])
```

I'm assuming you need the different capturing groups you used on your question. If that's not the case, you may remove them or replace them with non-capturing groups `(?:)`

I'm also assuming you don't need to capture the space on the capturing group, so I put it aside.

So the basic idea is that before your expression you may want to find either end of string/line `$` or some character that is not number, `-`, `/` or `.`.

Answer (score 1):

First this way may only work in the US (I tried it with a different `$timezone` but didn't work, but it could be a "try it out" issue).

Switch on `@sys-date`. If you user says "date 02/18 of" it will pick up 02/18 as 2020-02-18. You can then work with the date easier.

The other approach is to create a cloud function to do the complex regex for you and hand it back to Watson Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Watson Assistant Entity for testing, but this should work:

```
\s\d?\/\d?\s
```

or

```
\s\d{1,2)\/\d{1,2}\s
```

or

```
\s(\d|\d\d)\/(\d|\d\d)\s
```

where `\s` is white space, and `\d` is any digit

The site does not provide a proper manual with the abilities of the regex engine (at least, I did not find it). So I provided work-arounds for the said limitations.

---

It does not validate that the dates are realistic, but since `30/2` (February 30) is a valid match, there should be no problem.